# Evernote SetSharedSessionConsumerKey Does not Work in Outlook VBA Macro

Tags: evernote

I have a VBA macro in Outlook that moves a selected message into my archive folder and gets a url for the message.  I also would like to add the message to Evernote like the "Save to Evernote" add-in and automatically add the url to the message as the url of the note.

I downloaded the COM setup for the Evernote Cloud SDK:
https://github.com/evernote/evernote-cloud-sdk-windows/tree/master/COM%20Setup

I then registered for and received my Evernote API Key for this application (Consumer Key and Consumer Secret).

I have an account in the sandbox.

I added a reference to the Evernote Cloud SDK and wrote some simple code to test that it is working.

However, the following code fails when checking the `SharedSession.IsAuthenticated`.

The code:

```vbs
Public Sub CreateNote()
   Const Key = "MY KEY"
   Const Secret = "MY SECRET"
   Const Host = "sandbox.evernote.com"

   Dim evernoteSession As New ENSessionForCOM
   Call evernoteSession.SetSharedSessionConsumerKey(Key, Secret, Host)

   If evernoteSession.SharedSession.IsAuthenticated = False Then
       evernoteSession.SharedSession.AuthenticateToEvernote
   End If     
End Sub
```

The error:

```
Run-time error '-2147024809 (80070057)'

Cannot create shared Evernote session without either a valid
consumer key/secret pair, or a developer token set.
```

I thought maybe I was trying too soon, but it has been almost 24 hours. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of trial and error, I finally found a solution. Instead of an `ENSessionForCOM`, I needed to create an `ENSessionAdvancedForCOM` object. So now the code looks like this:

```
Public Sub CreateNote()
   Const Key = "MY KEY"
   Const Secret = "MY SECRET"
  Const Host = "sandbox.evernote.com"

   Dim evernoteSession As New ENSessionAdvancedForCOM
   Call evernoteSession.SetSharedSessionConsumerKey(Key, Secret, Host)

   If evernoteSession.SharedSession.IsAuthenticated = False Then
      evernoteSession.SharedSession.AuthenticateToEvernote
   End If     
End Sub
```

And it now authenticated.